# VS Code: & перед путем к файлу

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VS Code видит & перед путем к файлу, например `& C:/Users/mikja/AppData/Local/...`, и ругается на [SyntaxError: invalid syntax].

Перед путем к файлу интерпретатор упорно видит `&`, например `& C:/Users/mikja/AppData/Local/...`, хотя этого символа там нет.

Пример кода, при котором возникает ошибка:

```
import openpyxl as op

filename = 'Бланк заказа.xlsx'

wb = op.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
sheet = wb.active

max_rows = sheet.max_row

print(max_rows)

print(sheet.cell(row=7, column=2))
```

Я в питоне новенький, библиотеку эту не знаю, делаю по туториалу. Однако такая ошибка появляется не только в этом коде, так что вопрос скорее к правильным настройкам VS Code.
Поиск решения усложняет факт, что поисковики видят `&` как логический оператор, а не как часть запроса.

UPD: Что любопытно, спустя время вернулся к коду, и ошибка пропала. Спустя еще какое-то время появилась снова. Не уходит после возвращения кода в состояние, когда работал.

[image: Скриншот с ошибкой и кодом в VSCode]

UPD 2: '&' видно и при нормальной работе

[image: & перед адресом без ошибки]

UPD 3: Проблема оказалась не в '&', а в терминале. Через Powershell все работает, а через Python - нет

Только неясно, как менять терминал. Прилагаю скриншот со спорной ситуацией:

[image: 'Kill Terminal' для исправления ошибки?]

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Покажите скриншот с ошибкой что ли, если нет текстового трейса ошибки нормального.

Comment: Спасибо, что обратили внимание на проблему! Прикрепил скриншот. Ошибка пропадает и появляется независимо от кода

Comment: А попробуйте вот эти советы почитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540391/invalid-syntax-error-when-running-python-from-inside-visual-studio-code

Comment: Вкратце: попробуйте ввести exit() в терминале

Comment: @CrazyElf Ввел. И в терминал, и в powershell (хотя он ругатся). Проблема появилась снова. Заметил, что '&' VS Code видит и при нормальной работе. Новый скриншот прикрепляю к вопросу

Comment: В первом случае у вас строка запущена в интерактивном режиме Python: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mPGF.png, и Python ругается, потому что для него это некорректный синтаксис. Во втором случае - через powershell. Проблема не в &, а в способе запуска. Возможно перед запуском вы в терминале запустили Python и что-то там делали.

Answer (score 2):

Вы вручную запустили Python в интерактивном режиме, приглашение `>>>` в терминале который остался после запуска. Этот терминал привязан к отладчику VSCode, а он думает что там Powershell. Закрой этот терминал и запускай файл в новом.

В рабочем случае у Вас открыт терминал Powershell, приглашение `PS`. `&` корректная команда для Powershell, тоже самое что и `Start-Process`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Многое прояснилось. Но я по-прежнему не понимаю, как поменять терминал с python на powershell. В VSCode отображается терминал python, но в строке указано PS (Прикрепляю скриншот в обновленном вопросе)
Я правильно понимаю, что при ошибке необходимо выбрать 'Kill terminal' и запустить код снова?

Comment: 'Kill terminal' и запустить код снова - да